# What would be the common/best way to deal with common files in installers?

Tags: .net, installation, software-distribution

I currently on a project which will be used by a handful of other project. The project contains:

- some native dlls
- some managed dlls that p/invoke into native ones
- data - possibly quite big

I would like to provide separate installer for this project and other projects would detect if it is installed and use it if available.

What would be the best way to handle this ?

I have considered:

1. create installer with data only and have all other projects distribute my dlls on their own
2. create installer with everything and have other project locate my dlls and load them.

I have technical difficulty with #2, how would other projects use my dll? I rather avoid reflection. If I gac the dlls, how would my managed dlls find the native dlls?

EDIT:
I'm not looking for specific packager/installer with specific feature. I'm simply asking what is the best practice conceptually.

Comment: If your installer is MSI based then you should look into [Merge Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - it sounds very much like you should package your common components into a merge module for use by other installers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually used merge modules before so I thought I'd have a play and see how they worked.

A merge module allows you to package up common installer functionality into a re-usable module (typically installation components, but possibly also some setup UI).  Each application installer that uses this merge module is free to install these components wherever they want (for example alongside their application) and if they do multiple copies of these components will be installed, however if they are disciplined and all specify the same install location then only one copy of the components will be installed.

If the components are installed to a common location then things work quite nicely in that the components are only uninstalled once all the dependent installers have been uninstalled.  This is far simpler than having a separate installer for the common components as it means that each application installer doesn't need to worry about whether or not it should uninstall this common installer when being uninstalled (which could potentially break all other applications which use these components).

The tricky thing about this whole arrangement however is **versioning** - if *App A* installs *CommonLib* v1.0 and then *App B* installs *CommonLib* v1.1, what should happen?

- Definitely both versions of the .Net assembly should be installed - this could be solved either by installing to the GAC or by installing to a specific directory that includes a version number.
- Probably both versions of the native dll should be installed too.  Again this could either be solved by installing to WinSxS or by installing to a version-named directory.
- I guess that only 1 copy of the data should be installed, however if this is not the case then again you will need to install the data to different directories.

If multiple directories are used to separate versions then you should make sure that it is the merge module that decides the names of these directories, for example the directory structure of your common library might look like this:

```
Program Files
    Common Lib // This is the folder that installers must specify
        *Common data files*
        v1.0
            *v1.0 Files*
        v1.1
            *v1.1 Files*
```

This way even if an application installs v1.1 while accidentally leaving the common installation directory unchanged, it won't overwrite the v1.0 files.

(Note that there might be other more sophisticated ways of having the merge module specify the installation location, but I know that the above works so I didn't look into it too much as it probably depends on what you use to create your MSI - Wix / InstallShield etc...)

Also if you separate out your versions into different directories you will also need some mechanism to allow either your library or the end user Application identify where the the relevant files have been installed to (for example a registry key) - this is where installing to the GAC (or maybe just installing the managed library alongside the application) has its advantages as it means that this logic can be embedded into the library itself.

Ultimately how you do this will depend on your specific requirements, but I hope that this has at least given you some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

as Kragen mentioned, have a look at MSI Packaging process. We Use AdminStudio which is quite good to packaging up your binaries. Or you could WIX as well (which is command line packaging which usually gets integrated with the build)

Comment: -1 Have you even read the question? I'm not looking for something that can zip up my files.

Comment: i did, got carried over with word "installer" :) GAC could be an option for, that way when you release new binaries, old ones which are still shared among other will continue to work. for sharing data, you would have to package and distribute it somehow